# What is the cause of this grouping of floating particles at a very specific layer?

Tags: density, buoyancy

[image: The grouping of particles is quite apparent.]

This is a classic density sedimentation experiment for soil composition and I was quite puzzled as to why it occurred.

Any takers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a color variation in the fluid. This indicates that the composition is not uniform. I would expect that the lower part is denser.

I expect the particles are floating in fluid that matches their density.